# Query all tables to retrieve all columns names and data type

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

my problem:

I'm working with Athena, where we created many tables from our data in NetSuite. These tables are under a datasource called: AWSDataCatalog and a database called: dev_netsuite_jdbc_cleaned.

I've tried this command: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
But I got this error:

> HIVE_INVALID_METADATA: Hive metadata for table
> dump_delta_tagpeople_companies_parquet is invalid: Table descriptor
> contains duplicate columns
>
> This query ran against the "dev_netsuite_jdbc_cleaned" database,
> unless qualified by the query.

Basically, I need these information to find where we have stored our information to recreate on QuickSite the same results we obtain from some searches in Netsuite, so I need first to track where all the values are...

I'd like something like:

Table  Column    type
1      blabla   string
1      cities   string
2      names    value
2      etc
3      etc
4      etc

Could someone help me? Ty!

Comment: is this hdfs ? What is you are using ? hive/impala? If its hdfs, there is nothing like `all_tables` in oracle, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` sql server. If you need it, you need to create it using python or some script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is clearly spelled out in the error message: "table dump_delta_tagpeople_companies_parquet is invalid: Table descriptor contains duplicate columns"

You have a table called "dump_delta_tagpeople_companies_parquet" which contains duplicate columns. Recreate the table without the duplicate columns and things will work out.